# ibus: increase font size and spacing beween words

Tags: ibus

I use ibus to type in different languages. But for some reason for a language other than English the font size is always smaller and the spacing between words much smaller. Is there anyway I can customize these permanently? I have provided a screenshot of gedit with text entered in three languages - Telugu (rts), Sanskrit (harvard-kyoto) and English for comparison. In brackets, I have shown how it is supposed to look.

[image: Screenshot]

I have realized that word spacing is partly editor dependent. But the font size is invariably smaller. This is specially the case for Telugu.

Comment: With what languages have you experienced this?